# Postgresql Won't grant user access to database that is existent

Tags: postgresql, centos, privileges

I'd puzzled, being a newbie to postgresql.

I have a database named "Launch"

I'm running:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE Launch TO admin;
```

user `admin` has privileges like:
[image: img]

Additionally, running postgres command:

```
\list
```

yields the database "Launch"

The only thing I did see was, there was no entry for "Access Privileges" for the database `Launch`:
[image: img2]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lesson learned the long way:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE <yourdbhere> TO <youruserhere>;
```

the `<yourdbhere>` the db name MUST be in **lower case**. By using `Launch` for my db name - it was messing things up.